# Why does winget install use installation path to old linked user directory?

Tags: windows, winget

While installing a fresh `Windows-11 Home` edition, the install process created a very poorly named user home directory, and this without asking user for what they wanted to name their home. To remedy the situation a new user account was created and the old home directory was moved, but a soft link was made from old user directory (to new) in order to ensure system stability and loss of possible configuration files.

However, using `winget` to install [*AutoHotKey*](https://www.autohotkey.com/) (`AHK`), resulted in the creation of AHK settings files being created in old linked directory!

**Why does `winget` insist on using and knowing about this old users home directory?**

<sub>Bonus Question:

Where are these settings stored and can they be fixed/changed?</sub>

Comment: Why did you tag this question with `PowerShell`? Wouldn't you agree that this question actually belongs to [https://superuser.com](https://superuser.com)? Regardless of that - if it's a fresh installation I had created a new user and simply remove the one automatically created. ‍♂️

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it actually belongs to https://superuser.com.

Comment: I can agree on that, and someone with more SO rights could move it there if they like. I labelled it with powershell because all the post install changes had to be done in posh, and winget depends on posh as well.

Comment: If you referring to PowerShell when you use *posh* ... no, winget does not depend on *posh*. You can run it in `CMD.exe` if you like. It is just a CLI tool. ‍♂️